# Does doxygen have better filter for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, documentation, doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

I know that Doxygen doesn't support JavaScript files. I have also looked at js2doxy.pl script and also this:

[Documenting JavaScript with Doxygen](http://coherent-labs.com/blog/documenting-javascript-with-doxygen/)

The first option(js2doxy.pl) is not producing relevant C++ code, it is also skipping all the prototype methods and leave them blank. The second option is working but not for prototype based programming. I am looking for a filter which can support prototype based(OOP) JavaScript files. I researched a lot about it but I failed to find a better filter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If someone was willing to pay for it, of if users were willing to pay at least a one cent licence for it, this could be developed, but the answer to it is well known to be No to both.